# What is the locus of points diametrically opposed to any point $C$ on line $\ell \perp AB$ when taking the unique circle $\circ ABC$?

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry

> Consider distinct points $A,B$ and a line $\ell \perp AB$.  For any point $C \in \ell$, form the circle $\circ ABC$, and take $C'$ as the point on $\circ ABC$ diametrically opposite $C$.  What is the locus of such points $C'$?
>
> Source: Hadamard's *Geometry*

My solution is below, to which I request verification, feedback, and suggestions.  In particular: Is the exposition clear? How could it be improved?

---

**Solution:** Let line $p$ be the perpendicular bisector of $AB$.  The desired locus is the reflection of $\ell$ over $p$, which we call line $\ell'$.

**Proof:** For any $C$ chosen, $AB$ is a chord of $\circ ABC$, and therefore the center $O$ of $\circ ABC$ is on $p$.  Recall that the reflection $C'$ of any point $C$ over any point $O$ on line $p$ will have the same distance from line $p$ as $C$ itself has (as easily shown by AAS), and hence be on line $\ell'$.  Conversely, reflecting any point $C'$ on $\ell'$ will yield an appropriate point $C$, completing the proof.

**Update:** The problem as written isn't clear if $C$ may be the unique point $\ell \cap AB$ (in which case we form not a circle but a line).  If this is not allowed, we must also disallow the unique point $\ell' \cap AB$ as well.

Comment: Your solution is correct.